Bounding $L^2$ norm independently of $\hbar$ constant
Let the dimension be $d$ and $k\in\mathbb R^d$ be a constant I am trying to bound the $L^2_p$ norm of $$\hbar^{d-1}\Big(g(\hbar(p-k))-g(\hbar(p+k))\Big)e^{-i\hbar k\cdot p}$$ in a way that is independent of $\hbar$.
If I take the $p$- integral, I obtain $$\hbar^{d-1}\int_p\Big(g(\hbar(p-k))-g(\hbar(p+k))\Big)e^{-i\hbar k\cdot p}\,dp=\hbar^{d-1}F[g(\hbar(p-k))-g(\hbar(p+k))](\hbar k)$$
$$=\hbar^{-1}(e^{-i\hbar|k|^2\cdot x}-e^{i\hbar|k|^2})\widehat g(k)$$
$$=-2i\hbar^{-1}\sin(\hbar|k|^2)\widehat g(k)$$ using Fourier rules, which can be bounded independently of $\hbar$ by $|\sin(\hbar|k|^2)|/\hbar\leq|k|^2$.
But when I take the $L^2$ norm, $$\|{\hbar^{d-1}\Big(g(\hbar(p-k))-g(\hbar(p+k))\Big)e^{-i\hbar k\cdot p}}\|_{L^2_p}=\hbar^{d-1}\|{\Big(g(\hbar(p-k))-g(\hbar(p+k))\Big)}\|_{L^2_p}$$
$$=\hbar^{\frac{d}{2}-1}\|g(p-\hbar k)-g(p+\hbar k)\|_{L^2_p}$$
$$=\frac{\hbar^{\frac{d}{2}-1}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\|(e^{-i\hbar k\cdot x}-e^{i\hbar k\cdot x})\widehat g(x)\|_{L^2_x}$$
$$=\frac{\hbar^{\frac{d}{2}-1}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\|2\sin(\hbar k\cdot x)\widehat g(x)\|_{L^2_x}$$
$$\leq \frac{\hbar^{\frac{d}{2}}|k|}{(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\|x\widehat g(x)\|_{L^2_x},$$ my bound is no longer independent of $\hbar.$ Is there a way to bound the function in a way that does not depent on $\hbar$?

I would suggest rewriting your original function using non-dimensional variables.

@K.defaoite thank you for your response. How do I do that?

Well, presumably $p$ and $k$ have inverse square root physical units as $\hbar$, otherwise the expression $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \hbar p\cdot k}$ would be undefined. So I would come up with some suitable reference values $p_0$ and $k_0$ and introduce the non dimensional variables $\bar p=p/p_0$, $\bar k=k/k_0$, and then also the non-dimensional constants $a={p_0}^2 \hbar$, $b={k_0}^2 \hbar$ and rewrite, e.g
$$\hbar (p-k)=a p_0\bar p-bk_0\bar k$$
Then transform back into your physical units at the end.

Also what is the precise form of $g$ ? Note that its argument $\hbar (p\pm k)$ is dimensional.
